# Detect the exactly matched route of the current component in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I'm having a problem like this: For example, this is the route structure I used:

```
routes = [{
    "name": "Parent",
    "path": "",
    "component": () => import("@/views/Parent.vue"),
    "children": [{
        "name": "Child",
        "path": "child",
        "component": () => import("@/views/Child.vue"),
        "children": [{
            "name": "Grandchild",
            "path": "grandchild",
            "component": () => import("@/views/Grandchild.vue")
        }]
    }]
}]
```

When I go to the path `/child/grandchild`, is there any ways for the `Child.vue` to detect its own route name, which is `Child` instead of `Grandchild` using vue-router library.

I tried to use `useRoute` but all it gave me is the `Grandchild` route, instead of `Child` route.

Comment: `useRoute` will only contain information for the current route, but `useRouter` has details regarding all routes.  You've not specified why you need Child.vue to have information regarding the route associated with it when the current route does not match, but in general you could do something like `useRouter().getRoutes().find(r => r.name === 'componentName')` to get details of any specific component based route at any time.